# Tomcat 8 - Static external content - without changing server.xml

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I need to define a static content resource (external folder). Something like this

`<Context   docBase="C:/.../static"
            path="/static"/>`

But i am not allowed to modify tomcats `conf/server.xml`

Is it possible within a context.xml file or anywhere else in the webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on my own. Simply create `tomcat/Catalina/localhost/public.xml` :

`<Context docBase="c:/.../public" path="/public"/>`

Now the defined path will be available under /public.